# How to model different initial screen on app launch depending upon state with storyboards?

Tags: ios

Whenever my app launches one of 3 possible screens will be displayed depending upon the state.

I was going to model this in a storyboard by having the starting view controller as a navigation view controller, then have a segue from it to each of the three  other VCs.
Then on app launch the appropriate VC would get pushed depending upon the app's stored state.

However IB will not permit me to make multiple connections from the navigation controller.
If I make an initial segue from the NVC to any of the VCs, say A. Then when I attempt to add another segue from the NVC to another of the VC, B, then instead IB creates a connection between A and B.

First of all is the approach of having a Navigation Controller as a starting RVC and pushing different VCs onto depending on state an incorrect approach? If not, then how to model it with storyboards? Why will IB not let me drag and drop the segue to the other controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the navigation controller is the way to go. IB won't let you connect more than one, because that first connection is the root view controller, and there is only one of those.

There a many different ways you could get what you want depending on where you go after one of those 3 initial views. Do they all go to the same view next? All different view? Some the same, some different? It's hard to advise you without more detail.

You could start off with a tab bar controller, with the tab bar hidden, if you don't want that look. Or, you could have logic in the viewDidAppear method of a common initial controller, and have it switch the root view controller of the window to on of your three screens.

Comment: Thanks. How does this person get multiple segues from a NC? Are multiple segues therefore allowed, just not if the controller is the rvc? Why is it different for the rvc casehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548306/ios5-storyboard-multiple-segues-from-navigation-controller

Comment: @Mungbeans, you do a segue from the root view controller to the next controller, and that one does it to the following one etc. You're adding controllers onto the navigation controller's stack as you do these pushes, so you have to chain them, one to the next.